# Alternative to multiple inheritance in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I would like to use inheritance to enforce consistency in Entity Framework model classes.  For example, if X different models all have an address, they could inherit from:

```
public abstract class EntityAddress
{
    [MaxLength(400)]
    [Display(Name = "Street address")]
    [DataMember]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(400)]
    [Display(Name = "Address line 2")]
    [DataMember]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    [DataMember]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    [Display(Name = "Zip code")]
    [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
    [DataMember]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

This would ensure that all addresses are consistently implemented across the product (yes, if a model has two addresses, we have an issue, but I'll wave that away for the purposes of this discussion).

I would also like the ability to have a class use an unlimited number of these concepts.  For example, if a model has an address and a full name, it could do this:

```
public class Customer : EntityAddress, EntityFullName
{

}
```

Multiple inheritance, however, is not supported in C#.

Does anyone have any ideas on good alternate methods to achieve what I am trying to do here?  I don't believe interfaces will work because I can't embed the attributes with the properties.  I don't believe a class property will work because I want the columns in the DB associated with the base classes to be in the same table as the model class properties.

Comment: Use composition. A customer **Has** an address (a customer IS **not** an address).

Comment: EF could not translate one-to-one relationship as inheritance. In normal business case, customer could have multiple addresses. In addition, you could place full name inside customer class.

Comment: Looks like [Complex Types](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types) is what you need.

Comment: With standard classes, composition is the clear solution.  With EF, though, the structure of the class defines the tables in the database.  Using composition won't give the proper schema in the DB, I believe.

Comment: I'll review complex types, which looks basically like composition.  Thanks.  I'll update this with my findings.

Comment: Note that complex-types are not yet in EfCore.

Comment: Well, I think complex types were 90% of the solution to what I wanted.  I'll note that.  However, an added wrinkle; I use T4 templates to scaffold views and controllers.  Those templates loop through properties.  The complex type property doesn't loop through it's properties, so this solution isn't compatible with my added wrinkle requirement.

Comment: That's why T4 is _templates_. You can make it render complex types. Just a little bit of fun hacking in that black&white world.

Comment: Yep, I'm considering doing so.

Comment: Actually, templates do a much better job than I initially thought.  The index template had issues for me, but the create/edit/details/delete templates were usable and decent looking out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex types appear to be an answer to this question (credit to Ivan Stoev).

https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap in a class. Its not pretty, but it will achieve similar results

```
public class Customer 
{
   public EntityAddress address {get;set;}
   public EntityFullName fullname {get;set;}   
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a Customer table that has a relationship with an EntityAddress table and EntityFullName table in the database?  I am looking to have all properties map to a single table in the database.

Comment: Ah! Thats valid. You could wrap it outside of the entity framework. Create like a CustomerWrapper that includes the Customer, Address and Full name properties and then run the queries in the constructor when instantiated